# Java unicode name regexp

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I want to check user name and last name using java regexp. 
And I use this pattern

```
private static final Pattern CHECK_NAME_FIELD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\w+",
        Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

public static boolean checkNameField(String name){
    return CHECK_NAME_FIELD_PATTERN.matcher(name).matches();
}
```

But `checkNameField("234523")` returns true.

Comment: `\d` should work instead of `\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns true for the numbers because `\w` would match also the digits.

```
private static final Pattern CHECK_NAME_FIELD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+",
    Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

`\\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language.

Comment: I also want to check unicode names. Will [A-Za-z]+ work?